# Why isn't the flex element height transitioning gradually?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I basically have a page with some `flex` elements in it that I want to grow in size (to the viewport height to be exact) but I want it to have a gradual transition which I have not been able to accomplish.
Here is a mockup of my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn-showmore').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'height': '100vh'
    })
    $(this).siblings('p').show()
    $(this).hide()
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 720px;
  display: grid; 
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 1s;
}

.banner {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.banner-content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaaaaa77;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  transition: 1s;
}

.banner-1 {
  background-color: #82c0ff;
}

.banner-2 {
  background-color: #f3ff82;
}

.banner-3 {
  background-color: #82ff93;
}

.hidden-info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="banner banner-1">
      <div class="banner-content">
        <h2>Awesome Info</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn-showmore">SHOW MORE</a>
        <p class="hidden-info">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium alias a est aspernatur corrupti fuga molestias totam saepe, eaque odit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner banner-2">
      <div class="banner-content">
        <h2>Awesome Info</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn-showmore">SHOW MORE</a>
        <p class="hidden-info">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium alias a est aspernatur corrupti fuga molestias totam saepe, eaque odit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner banner-3">
      <div class="banner-content">
        <h2>Awesome Info</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn-showmore">SHOW MORE</a>
        <p class="hidden-info">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium alias a est aspernatur corrupti fuga molestias totam saepe, eaque odit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see the element inside the '.banner' grows with the transition as intended, but the `.banner` itself it's all jaggy and grows by steps. Hopefuly someone will be able to help me with this convoluted question...

Comment: what about no using display flex?...

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you're talking about in the snippet you provided. What browser are you testing on?

Comment: @DanMullin both chrome and safari has this "issue"

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I dropped the grid and changed some styles down a level, made a small tweak to your JS and it seems to work fine now. (You still need to scroll the page to the relevant div, though.)
I've found that for transitions to work, they need a clearly defined starting and ending value, e.g. 240px and 100vh.

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn-showmore').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.banner').css({
      'height': '100vh'
    });
    $(this).siblings('p').show();
    $(this).hide();
  })
})

body {margin:0;}

.banner {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 240px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition: 1s;
}

.banner-content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaaaaa77;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  transition: 1s;
}

.banner-1 {
  background-color: #82c0ff;
}

.banner-2 {
  background-color: #f3ff82;
}

.banner-3 {
  background-color: #82ff93;
}

.hidden-info {
  display: none;
}
```